# wxPython: Making a panel in the frame the parent, it will hold and remove all other panels. But, can't display the panels

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I want to display some panels under a primary panel within the frame. Each child panel handles a particular functionality. Each child panel appears under the primary panel according to menu button clicks.

I tried to apply this. When the app is opened, a default panel, called `HomePanel`, is shown under the primary panel. But, when I click on a menu its corresponding panel isn't showing. Instead, a blank screen is coming.

This is the default panel or `IntroPanel` placed inside the primary panel. This is shown when the app is opened:

```
import wx

class IntroPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Left panel-----------------------------------------------------
        left_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE, size=(250, 600))
        main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 1)
        left_panel.SetBackgroundColour('red'0
        
        # Right panel-----------------------------------------------------
        right_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
        right_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#f8f8ff')
        main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 1, wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, 2)
       
        self.Center()
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()
```

This is the `ProductsPanel`. I want to show it in the primary panel by removing the `IntroPanel`. Which isn't displaying:

```
import wx

class ProductsNotebookPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        
        sizer = wx.Sizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        
        sample_txt = wx.StaticText(self, label="Hello Patients")
        sizer.Add(sample_txt, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Finally, this is the frame definition:

```
import wx

class GUIFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(
            parent, title="ABC Drugs Inventory Management 0.0.1",  size=(1280, 720)
            )

        self.InitMenuBar()
        
        self.main_frame_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.main_frame_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.active_panel = IntroPanel(self.main_frame_panel)
        self.main_frame_sizer.Add(self.active_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 2)
        self.main_frame_panel.SetSizer(self.main_frame_sizer)

        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def InitMenuBar(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        quit = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit', 'Close')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, quit)
        
        # Create Product Menu and its CRUD options as sub-menus
        productsMenu = wx.Menu()
        view_product = productsMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'View')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.handleProducts, view_product)
        productsMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Add')
        productsMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Modify')
        productsMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Remove')
     
        # Append menu items to the MenuBar
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        menubar.Append(productsMenu, '&Products')

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    def handleProducts(self, event):
        self.main_frame_sizer.GetChildren().GetWindow().Destroy()
        self.active_panel = ProductsNotebookPanel(self.main_frame_panel)        
        self.main_frame_sizer.Add(self.active_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 2)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUIFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

What I'm getting is this:
[image: 1st]

And when clicking on any other menu item, nothing is happening!

Finally, How do I display all my panels under  the primary panel?

Comment: self.main_frame_sizer.GetChildren() returns a list of windows, cannot use GetWindow()